# Cause of video artifact/artefact

Tags: java, video, encode, decode, playback

![alt text][1]

The above screenshot shows some artifacting which is occuring during a software decode of a .DV video file, compliant to SMPTE 314m...

The artefacting is believed to be cause by a AC/DC coefficient problem, is this likely?

Any information is appreciated.

Comment: can you post a screen capture of the original frame for comparison?

Comment: Voting to close, this is pointless now.

Comment: Uhm, might want to leave the question in place in future so that others can see what the problem / solution was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is.  The blockiness would seem to indicate you are decoding the AC coefficients incorrectly.  The good news is that it appears every macro block is being decoded incorrectly.  If nothing else, they are too dark.  Thus I would step through the decoding of a single block.  Do the math by hand and then watch it decode in the debugger.  See where the numbers diverge.

Comment: I have various yCbCr -> RGB conversion methods, none color correct although some better than others.

Thanks for the feedback regarding the method of correction though, I'll give it a try!

Comment: If you figure it out, let us know what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you might not be decoding the frame compression correctly...

-Adam

Comment: Ah, you are right. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DV  There is compression on each frame, though.  Are you decompressing each frame correctly?

Comment: @Steve - DV has intraframe compression, but according to wikipedia (which, of course, is an unassailable bastion of truth ;-) it doesn't not have interframe compression.  Thus each frame is compressed individually, and does not depend on any other frame for information.

Comment: @Adam, that's all I-frames.  P and B frames are the inter-frame compression frames.